# How to eliminate the MessageBeep from the RICHEDIT control?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, reverse-engineering, richedit

The [RichEdit control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/about-rich-edit-controls) has this very annoying feature. It beeps every time the user tries to move the cursor past its "*end point*". For instance, you can test it with the `WordPad` that also implements RICHEDIT. Open it up, type in some text, then hit the `Home` key. If the cursor was not in the beginning of the line:

[image]

hitting `Home` key will move it there, but then hitting the `Home` key again will produce this beep.

At first glance it seemed like overriding `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages and blocking the situations when RICHEDIT can produce that beep was a solution ... until I actually started implementing it. Unfortunately though, it's not as simple as it sounds, as that control beeps in a LOT OF CASES! So my keystroke blocking code literally ballooned to over 300+ lines, and I still see that there are some key-presses that I either didn't account for, or worse, I might have overridden some useful behavior with. (Read below for more details.)

---

Then I decided to look inside the implementation of the RICHEDIT control itself. And sure enough, for instance if we look at the implementation of the `Home` key press, the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msftedit.dll` on my Windows 10 OS, has the function called `?Home@CTxtSelection@@QAEHHH@Z` (or `public: int __thiscall CTxtSelection::Home(int,int)` demangled) at the mapped offset `0x3FC00`, that is hard-coded to call the [MessageBeep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep)(MB_OK), or **exactly** what I'm trying to eliminate:

[image]

And if you look at the address `0x6B64FD38` in the screenshot above, there's a built-in way to bypass it, with what looks to be flag `0x800`.

So having dug into `msftedit.dll` a little bit more, there appears to be a function called `?OnAllowBeep@CTxtEdit@@QAEJH@Z` (or `public: long __thiscall CTxtEdit::OnAllowBeep(int)` demangled) that can modify this flags:

[image]

After a bit more research I found out that there are COM interfaces built into RICHEDIT control, such as `ITextServices` and `ITextHost` that reference that flag as `TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP` in [`ITextServices::OnTxPropertyBitsChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/textserv/nf-textserv-itextservices-ontxpropertybitschange) method.

Unfortunately though, I can't seem to find the way how I can directly change that `TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP` flag (COM is not my forte.) I tried looking into implementing [`ITextHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/textserv/nl-textserv-itexthost), but it has a lot of virtual methods that have nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve that I don't know how to implement.

Does anyone have any idea how to clear that `TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP` flag?

---

*PS. Here's why I didn't go the route of overriding key-presses:
Just to give you an example. Say, if I override the `VK_HOME` key press. I need to make sure that the cursor is not at the beginning of the line, but also that there's no selection. Yet, I need to make sure that `Ctrl` key is not down in a situation when the cursor is at the very top of the window. Then the same with the `Shift` key, and I'm not even sure what `Alt` does with it ... and so forth. Oh, and this is just the `Home` key. There's also Up, Down, Left, Right, PageUp, PageDown, End, Delete, Backspace. (And that's what I was aware of. There may be more, plus I'm not even talking about IME or other keyboard layouts, etc.) In other words, it becomes a mess!
So, eventually I realized that anticipating a keystroke **is not** the way to go.*

Comment: really we need [`EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-getoleinterface) send to richedit window and then query `ITextServices` interface and call `pTxtSrv->OnTxPropertyBitsChange(TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP, 0);` all is simply, but no such answer under linked question

Comment: i post answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885061/6401656). dont know need duplicate it under this question too, or how

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first we need send [`EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-getoleinterface) message to rich edit window - this is Retrieves an IRichEditOle object that a client can use to access a rich edit control's Component Object Model (COM) functionality.

then for retrieve an [`ITextServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/textserv/nl-textserv-itextservices) pointer, call `QueryInterface` on the private `IUnknown` pointer returned by [`EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/em-getoleinterface).

here exist interesting point - the `IID_ITextServices` not well known but need get in runtime from *Msftedit.dll*

from [About Windowless Rich Edit Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-windowless-rich-edit-controls)

> *Msftedit.dll* exports an interface identifier (IID) called **IID_ITextServices** that you can use to query the IUnknown pointer for the **ITextServices** interface.

after we got [`ITextServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/textserv/nl-textserv-itextservices) pointer - we simply can call [`OnTxPropertyBitsChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/textserv/nf-textserv-itextservices-ontxpropertybitschange) with `TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP` mask

code example:

```
#include <textserv.h>

if (HMODULE hmodRichEdit = LoadLibrary(L"Msftedit.dll"))
{
    // create richedit window
    if (HWND hwndRich = CreateWindowExW(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, ...))
    {
        if (IID* pIID_ITS = (IID*) GetProcAddress(hmodRichEdit, "IID_ITextServices"))
        {
            IUnknown* pUnk;
            if (SendMessageW(hwndRich, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, (LPARAM)&pUnk))
            {
                ITextServices* pTxtSrv;
                HRESULT hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(*pIID_ITS, (void**)&pTxtSrv);
                pUnk->Release();
                if (0 <= hr)
                {
                    pTxtSrv->OnTxPropertyBitsChange(TXTBIT_ALLOWBEEP, 0);
                    pTxtSrv->Release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, dude, you saved my bacon again! But dang it, I almost got it myself. All the way digging thru IDA, got all the internals but then that dang COM stumped me. Anyway, appreciate the help!

Comment: @c00000fd - i think under debugger more easy got from where `MessageBeep` is called and which object member we query, which interfaces it implement - unlike static code tools it take only several mins. really. then main point know about `EM_GETOLEINTERFACE`

Comment: Oh, you mean you got it solved that quickly after I posted this question?

Comment: @c00000fd - yes, near 5-10 min for research and the same time for test in code

Comment: Dang it, that's impressive, bro!