# Stop RichTextBox from beeping

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I have a simple form containing rich text box. When trying to navigate using the cursor keys from it beeps if the caret can't be moved - for example, pressing Home key when the caret is already on start of line, or trying to move line up when the caret is already on top line. Is there a way to disable those beeps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove annoying BEEP with RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683663/how-to-remove-annoying-beep-with-richtextbox).  Ignore the marked answer and read the other two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the ding (beeps) noise from being triggered each time when you press cursor keys or home key, then unfortunately it doesn't seems to be possible. But yeah, you can do it in some specific ways (i.e. using `AcceptButton`, `CancelButton` form property described [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290967/stop-the-ding-when-pressing-enter).

Comment: Hi Rohan, I thought along the same lines and my code now checks if the caret have where to go, and if not I set e.handled to True. Thank You.

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you can use e.Handled too but I didn't suppose if that's what you were asking in the question.